# What is the initial semiring category with a (commutative) semiring?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, semirings, internalization

Recall that

- The biinitial [monoidal category with a monoid](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/115517/what-is-the-free-monoidal-category-generated-by-a-monoid) is given by the augmented simplex category together with the monoid $([0],\sigma^{0}_{0},\delta^{0}_{0})$ there.
- The biinitial [symmetric monoidal category with a commutative monoid](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/117939) is given by the pair $(\mathsf{FinSets},*)$ consisting of the category of finite sets and morphisms between them equipped with the coproduct as the monoidal structure, and the triple
  $(*,*\coprod*\to*,\emptyset\to*)$ with $*$ the punctual set as the
  commutative monoid.

There's a natural notion of a [semiring object in a semiring category](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403014). Do we know what, if it exists, is the biinitial semiring category with a (commutative) semiring object?

Comment: Regarding the second bullet, I think you want to say that the initial _symmetric_ monoidal category with a commutative monoid is given by the category of finite sets and _all_ maps (not just bijections), with the cocartesian monoidal structure. The groupoid of finite sets is the initial symmetric monoidal category on _no data_.

Comment: Oh, right! Thanks, Tim!

Comment: @TimCampion [Pedantic mode on] The initial symmetric monoidal category with no data is actually the contractible category. The groupoid of finite sets is the initial symmetric monoidal category on one object [Pedantic mode off]

Comment: Oh geez of course, thanks!

Comment: I think that the category has objects the polynomial functors $\mathbf{FinSet} \to \mathbf{FinSet}$. The universal semiring object has underlying object $X$ (the identity), and every object has the form $\sum_i a_i X^{n_i}$. The tricky part is to work out the morphisms. For example, $\hom(X^n,X^m) = \hom_{\mathbf{FinOrd}}(n,m)$ and $\hom(n X,m X) = \hom_{\mathbf{FinSet}}(n,m)$, but $\hom(\sum_i a_i X^{n_i},\sum_j b_k X^{m_j})=?$. Probably it's a kind of semidirect product.